# Are there any modules for Profile2 revisioning/moderation

Tags: users

We're using Workbench moderation, and have a new requirement to add revisioning to the profile2 content. The primary reason for this is ensure that users' profile data has some degree of moderation before being made live.

If there is no current module solution for this, can anybody suggest the steps needed to create a module for this functionality.

Comment: Did you check out [this](https://drupal.org/node/1043128) thread in the Profile2 issue queue?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. There is a [patch for profile revisions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1043128) here.
2. There is a [Profile 2 Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_moderation) module.

(I will update this answer as I'll be trying out both of these.)